# preactjs, onclick toggler firing twice

Tags: javascript, dom-events, preact

I've encountered a weird behaviour with preactjs, weird because it never happened to me with react. Look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8s4vhknt/

It's a super simple component with a button which acts as a toggler.
Please open the browser console and look at the console logs.

Initially the active state prop is false -> INACTIVE.
When you first click the question mark, as expected, the toggle function is called, the target being the button (**N.B. in my local environment the event target turns out to be the '.help-overlay' element instead (which should be rendered only after the state changes), any ideas?**)

Then the state active prop is set to true, the component is rendered again -> ACTIVE in the console and the button changes.

Now clicking on the button will fire the `onclick` event twice and clearly nothing changes.

**I know, that this stuff has to do with event propagation in some way, and in fact, adding `e.stopPropagation()` at the beginning of the toggle function does the job**.

But what I'm not understanding is why! I mean, the event should propagate upwards through the dom, why the hell should fire again the same `onclick` handler on the same element?

This is why I'm not asking for a solution, but for an explanation of what is going on that I can't grasp.

I'll post here the code of the component ad in the fiddle.

```
const { h, render, Component } = preact;    // normally this would be an import statement.

class Help extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {active: false}
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this)
  }

  toggle (e) {
    console.log('ONCLICK', new Date().getTime(), e.target)
    this.setState(state => ({active: !state.active}))
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.state.active) {
      console.log('NOT ACTIVE')
      return (
        <div class='help-btn' onClick={this.toggle}>?</div>
      )
    } else {
      console.log('ACTIVE')
      return (
        <div class='help-overlay'>
          <div class='help-btn' onClick={this.toggle}>✕</div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

// render an instance of Clock into <body>:
render(<Help />, document.body);
```

Comment: It's something to do with the `<div class='help-overlay'>` element. If you wrap both of the elements with `<div class='help-overlay'>` or remove it altogether it will work as expected. not sure why though, maybe because the inner elements doesn't really change in the VDOM but get re-registered at the DOM?

Comment: Hi @Sagivb.g, thanks. I think you could've spot the point here. But I'd say the opposite: two virtual dom elements for one real, because otherwise I can't imagine how two handlers on different real dom events could fire twice. While two virtual dom elements tied to the same dom element could react (ahah) both if this dom element got fired. But in any case this sounds like a bug to me (react does not behave this way, proved). And also I can't understand why the stopPropagation call fixes this stuff. bye!

Comment: Don't forget that these are synthetic events in react but not in preact (as far as i know). Would be nice if you post an issue there and link it here so we can follow up.

Comment: Maybe you can add your example [in this issue](https://github.com/developit/preact/issues/838)

Comment: I'll file an issue, thanks

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that issue with Preact X. Looks like it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

div with overlay class in one dom and not in other create a vdom diff that will initiate the trigger for re-render.
I have wrap both div with parent div contains the conditional overlay class and it's working as expected.

```
.help-btn {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.help-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

/** @jsx h */
const { h, render, Component } = preact;    // normally this would be an import statement.

class Help extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {active: false};
  }

  toggle (e,isActive) {
    console.log('ONCLICK', new Date().getTime(), e.target)
    this.setState({active:!isActive});
  }

  render (props,{active}) {
        return (
        <div class={active ? "help-overlay" : "" }>
        {!active && <div class='help-btn' onClick={e => this.toggle(e,false)}>?</div>}
        {active && <div class='help-btn' onClick={e => this.toggle(e,true)}>✕</div>}
        </div>
      )
  }
}

// render an instance of Clock into <body>:
render(<Help />, document.body);
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nhkz4feq/

Comment: Hi @front_end_dev, thanks for your answer. I know I can solve the problem, still my question stays. "overlay class in one dom and not in other create a vdom diff that will initiate the trigger for re-render" , i don't think this is the point. The dom is not re-rendered because of its difference, which does not exist until it's re-rendered, it is re-rendered because the state changes. I think Savig b.g could have spot the point.